# Showing different content based on $_SESSION UserLevel

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am having a problem with trying to show different menu options based on UserLevel. I have a mysql database with a users table. The users table contains a UserLevel which will either be set to 0 or 1. But for some reason my php just isn't working. In fact, when I add the php to the menu, it then does not display ANYTHING on the site below the menu. Any advice would be much appreciated.

### Code that starts session

```
<?php  
if(!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Username']))  
{  

 ?>

<?php include "mainNav.php"; ?>  


<center>

    <h2> Campaign Updates</h2>

</center>

<div id="campaignPostWrap">
<div id="campaignScrollBox">

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dorians","ds2953!b67P$","aldentec");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns ORDER BY postDate desc");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div id='campaignPostContainer'>";
  echo "<ul class='campaignPostBox'>";
  echo "<p class='postInfo'>";
  echo "Posted on:";
  echo "<li>" . $row['postDate'] . "</li>";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<p class='postInfo'>";
  echo "Posted by:";
  echo "<li>" . $row['postName'] . "</li>";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<li class='postEntry'>" . $row['postEntry'] . "</li>";
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<hr>";
  }


mysqli_close($con);
?>

</div>
<?php include "campaignPost.php"; ?>
</div>


<?php include "chat.php"; ?>  

<?php
}  
elseif(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))  
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));     

    $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");  

    if(mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1)  
    {  
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);  
        $email = $row['EmailAddress'];  
        $userlevel = $row['UserLevel'];

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;  
        $_SESSION['EmailAddress'] = $email;  
        $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['UserLevel'] = $userlevel;  

        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";  
        echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area. If you are not automatically redirected <a href='index.php'>Click here</a></p>";  
        header( "refresh:10;url=index.php" );  
    }  
else  
    {  
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";  
        echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";  
    }  
}  
else  
{  
    ?>
```

### Menu code that isn't working

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

$userlevel = $_SESSION['UserLevel'];

if($userlevel == 0) {
    echo "<ul class="mainNav">
        <a href="characterRoll.php"><li> Create Character</li></a>
        <a href="questCreate.php"><li> Create Quest</li></a>
        <a href="characterView.php"><li> View Characters</li></a>
        <a href="questList.php"><li> View Quests</li></a>
        <a href="booksView.php"><li> Book List</li></a>
    </ul>";

} elseif($userlevel == 1) {

    echo "<a href="dmTools.php"><li> DM Tools</li></a>";
}
?>

<?php include "greeter.php"; ?>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some code in your post. Your first code block starts off with an `elseif`. Where is the first `if`?...

Comment: I didn't really think that part of the code would be needed, but I have edited my post to show it.

Comment: Isn't working is a very difficult problem to diagnose and fix. Please be more specific.

Comment: `echo "<ul class="mainNav">
        <a href="characterRoll.php">` You can't do this. You need to either use a single quote after `echo ` or escape the `"` like: `\"`

Comment: I strongly recommend that you find another way for handling your user roles as by sessions is not secure at all!

Comment: @crush To be more specific, when I wrap the <ul> in the php code it then shows blank from this code down on the page. If I take away all the php in the menu, and just have the <ul> it all works great.

Comment: @Aldentec You must have errors suppressed, or they are in the source code (likely).

Comment: @BjarkeBraskRubeksen Honestly, I thought this would be the easiest way. I am not super concerned about security as this is not a site that will be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes are undoubtedly the problem here:

```
if($userlevel == 0) {
    echo "<ul class="mainNav">
        <a href="characterRoll.php"><li> Create Character</li></a>
        <a href="questCreate.php"><li> Create Quest</li></a>
        <a href="characterView.php"><li> View Characters</li></a>
        <a href="questList.php"><li> View Quests</li></a>
        <a href="booksView.php"><li> Book List</li></a>
    </ul>";

} elseif($userlevel == 1) {

    echo "<a href="dmTools.php"><li> DM Tools</li></a>";
}
```

*Notice the syntax highlighting above shows the issue in your string. See how it turns black when it gets to `mainNav`? That's because `mainNav` is no longer part of the string. That's a bad thing here.*

Look at the first line of your `echo`:

```
echo "<ul class="mainNav">
```

You open a quote and then close it at `class="`. Now, it's trying to evaluate `mainNav` as a constant or some other language construct. On top of that, it doesn't know what to do with `mainNav` as you haven't provided any kind of operators.

Instead, you should do something like:

```
if($userlevel == 0) {
    echo '<ul class="mainNav">
        <a href="characterRoll.php"><li> Create Character</li></a>
        <a href="questCreate.php"><li> Create Quest</li></a>
        <a href="characterView.php"><li> View Characters</li></a>
        <a href="questList.php"><li> View Quests</li></a>
        <a href="booksView.php"><li> Book List</li></a>
    </ul>';

} elseif($userlevel == 1) {

    echo '<a href="dmTools.php"><li> DM Tools</li></a>';
}
```

Alternatively, you could escape every location where there is a non-string-terminating quote like `\"`.

Another option would be to use [**Heredoc**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Comment: Ok I feel dumb now. Thank you so much for the help on this @crush ! The the quotes were absolutely the problem.